# Maximum flow in undirected graph with non-integer weights

Tags: graph, max-flow

If I would want to find maximum flow in undirected graph, how could I do this?

On Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem it says that algorithms require directed graphs (I would just convert each edge to a pair of edges) but the problem is that I may have non integer weights (for example 0.5).

Is there any existing algorithm that is suitable for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [stoer-wagner algorithm](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~pcp/stoer-wagner.pdf) does the job. it dwells on the duality of max-flow/min-cut. an algorithm in the vein of the seminal [ford-fulkerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) (which fails on real-valued edge weights) would be [edmonds-karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for answer, it looks it will do :).